# ClassNotFoundException on runtime in a library module of my project

Tags: java, android, gradle, module

1. I have an Android project in Android Studio;

   2. And I create a java-library module (the steps is: `File -> New -> New Module -> Java library`);
   3. I add a third library by gradle, such as: "compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'";
   4. then, I use the OkHttpClient in my Main class's main method, It ok, compile successfully.
   5. **But I run the Main method, the console print errors:**

```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/OkHttpClient
        at com.zhang.anan.mylib.myClass.main(myClass.java:12)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.OkHttpClient
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

```

Comment: It looks like the JAR is not packed into the APK.

Comment: same problem here, how do you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Oracle documentation, [ClassNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) is thrown following the failure of a class loading call, using its string name, as per below:

- The Class.forName method
- The ClassLoader.findSystemClass method
- The ClassLoader.loadClass method
  In other words, it means that one particular Java class was not found or could not be loaded at runtime from your application current context class loader.

**How to resolve**

- Identify the caller :From the stack trace just before the Class.forName() or ClassLoader.loadClass() calls. This will help you understand if your application code is at fault vs. a third party API.
- Determine if your application code is not packaged properly e.g. missing JAR file(s) from your classpath.
- If the missing Java class is not from your application code, then identify if it belongs to a third party API you are using as per of your Java application. Once you identify it, you will need to add the missing JAR file(s) to your runtime classpath or web application WAR/EAR file.